# What is cause my pantry LEDs to turn on slowly, and how can I mitigate it?

Tags: power-supply, led

Recently I put an switched outlet in my pantry with a door jamb switch. A set of LEDs is plugged into that outlet.

When the LED set is plugged in, and I turn on an inline switch on the LED, the lights turn on instantly.

When I use the door jamb switch (with the inline switch on the LEDs turn on) the lights take a few seconds to turn on. This behavior can also be seen when just plugging and unplugging the power plug from a non switched outlet.

I'm thinking this tells me the power plug is what's causing the delay. It converts the standard 120 into 12v 1000 mA. Is there anything I can do (maybe replace the power plug?) to speed up it's response time?

Comment: Are you saying that the outlet in the pantry is switched on/off by the door jam switch?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, kind of like a refridgerator (but the switch is rated for 120v)

Comment: I think Trevor has the answer you need: leave the power supply on all the time and have both the switches in the 12 V supply to the LEDs.

Comment: Related, this question on diy.se... http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109077/would-it-be-out-of-code-to-switch-a-receptical-this-way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power supply probably takes a little while to wind up.

**If you can, break into the inline switch of the LEDS then:**

Completely disconnect the door jamb switch from your current outlet wiring. The outlet should be rewired so it is always on.

Break into the LED wiring and run the wires from the door jamb switch to connect in parallel to the inline-switch.

Switching the DC is A LOT SAFER than switching the mains anyway.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, true enough, though if he is switching mains to the brick, I'd bet its well over-rated for the other.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Depends on the switch I guess...

Comment: Either way he would be better to have the switch on the low voltage side.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If you're interested, this answer led me to a followup question. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294155/which-connector-would-i-use-for-a-non-standard-low-voltage-wall-connection-how

Answer (score 1):

OP has been circulating questions on this for awhile.  OP has a mains-wired door jamb switch, which supplies a receptacle.  OP went to a [lot of trouble](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109077/would-it-be-out-of-code-to-switch-a-receptical-this-way) to fish the wires for that jamb switch.

The receptacle supplies AC power to the DC power supply for the lighting.  This power supply has a couple seconds of "boot-up" delay.  Annoying.  And OP has correctly deduced this.

Apparently he has another way to switch off the LEDs that is instant.  This is switching the DC, the AC power supply stays spun-up.

Trevor is exactly right, the way to do this is simplify the AC power section so it powers the receptacle 24x7 (there will be some vampire load from the DC power supply).  Then convert the door-jamb run to switching 12 volts DC instead of AC mains. AFIAK he did it to Code and the wire will be at least 14AWG.  OP will need to be careful about this due to the requirement to separate low-voltage wiring from mains.

(There's an "All-in, or all-out" doctrine when it comes to mixing low voltage with mains.  Your low-voltage circuit can't hop bric-a-brc into mains electrical boxes and out again to be stapled along a bit of door trim like a phone wire. It must be 100% separate with dividers in boxes; *unless* you run every single part of the low-voltage to Class 1 mains wiring standard, conduit, romex, junction boxes, full monty.  I'm thinking of doing exactly that for a lighting-control circuit.)

Comment: +1 I'm surprised you found my question on DIY.SE! I wound up using a segregated high low voltage double gang box.

Comment: The 'vampire load' might not be insignificant.  If the pantry is lit fifteen minutes a day, and the power supply gives 10W at 90 percent efficiency, you use 2.75 watt-hours a day switching the AC.  But if the AC is always on, you use 24 watt-hours each day even when the light is NOT on.

Comment: @Whit3rd While the vampire load is an order of magnitude more than without, it should be noted that at least in the US we're charged pennies per KwH, so .024 kWh * 31 day * $.11 / kWh = $.08 per month. Also, per Trevor's answer, since switching DC is safer, I think 8 cents / month would be a reasonable "insurance" premium.

Comment: @Whit3rd my rule of thumb is $1 per watt per year, presuming 11.4 cents a kwh.

Comment: The DC switch idea is likely to be a maintenance problem: reliable DC sensors for alarm systems use reed switches which are sealed-in-glass and have high conductivity plated contacts.  A reed switch doesn't work with high LED currents (melts the plating), and other (microswitch) designs aren't usually low-V reliable.  Microswitches work fine on 48V up (and on AC).