# Which connector would I use for a non standard low voltage wall connection? How can I label it?

Tags: plug, home-installation

[(Please see this question for background info)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294151/what-is-cause-my-pantry-leds-to-turn-on-slowly-and-how-can-i-mitigate-it?noredirect=1#comment675163_294151)

In my pantry, I'm going to be connecting a door jamb switch across a low voltage application. I'd like to (instead of fishing the bare wire through a hole the wall) use a wall-plate with two connectors. [I see that banana plugs can support 30v at 15a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_connector#Electrical_safety) (way more than I would need), and come in a keystone jack. I am wondering though if using connectors typically for audio would present a hazard and if there is a better option that would be available in a keystone jack or standard wallplate.

Comment: Is the 'low voltage' AC or DC?  Banana plugs are NOT POLARIZED, can be wired backward on a DC system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use banana's but they are notoriously unreliable for falling out when you don't want them too.

Phono-Plugs make a MUCH more reliable mechanical connection.

[image]

Or go with a coaxial cable.

[image]

As for labels, get some printable labels.